# How to prevent escaping of a Twig Node Expression?

Tags: php, twig

I'm trying to implement [spread attributes](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/07bbe37bc42b6d4aef81) in [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). I've nearly got it, but I'm not sure how to prevent the ouput from being HTML-escaped.

I've registered my new operator in a `Twig_Extension`:

```
public function getOperators() {
    return [
        [/* Unary Operators */
            '...' => array('precedence' => 10, 'class' => SpreadAttributes::class),
        ],
        [/* Binary Operators */
            // ...
        ]
    ];
}
```

My class looks like this:

```
class SpreadAttributes extends Twig_Node_Expression_Unary {
    public function compile(Twig_Compiler $compiler) {
        $compiler
            ->raw(\WXUtility::class . '::html_attrs(')
            ->subcompile($this->getNode('node'))
            ->raw(')');
    }

    public function operator(Twig_Compiler $compiler) {
        throw new \Exception("Unused");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<label{{ ...label_attrs }}>
```

But the compiled output looks like this:

```
 echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, WXUtility::html_attrs((isset($context["label_attrs"]) ? $context["label_attrs"] : $this->getContext($context, "label_attrs"))), "html", null, true);
```

I need to get rid of that `twig_escape_filter` as `WXUtility::html_attrs` already generates escaped HTML.

How can I prevent the escaping?

---

I think this is doable but it's quite complicated. At some point in time the compiler creates a `Twig_Node_Print` which writes out the `echo` statement. On line 73 of `vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/NodeVisitor/Escaper.php` we can see it calls `escapePrintNode` in `leaveNode`. `escapePrintNode` calls `$node->getNode('expr')` which returns an instance of our `SpreadAttributes`. That's then passed off to `isSafeFor` which returns true if it's safe (doesn't need escaping). If it's not safe, it applies `twig_escape_filter`.

So we just need to override `Twig_NodeVisitor_Escaper::isSafeFor` or  `Twig_NodeVisitor_SafeAnalysis::getSafe`.

`$twig->removeExtension` is deprecated, so I can't remove the default `Escaper` extension. I guess I have to override `Twig_Environment` to take it out of the constructor. And then from there override `getNodeVisitors`. And then `isSafeFor`. But `Twig_Node_Expression` don't have any useful properties I can check; best I can do is `instanceof SpreadAttributes` and that's a major hack.

Is there no better way?

Comment: Wouldn't the [raw](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#output-escaping-in-twig) filter work?

Comment: @Orangepill How do I apply raw inside the `SpreadAttributes` class? I don't want to have to write `{{ ...label_attrs|raw }}` everywhere. Given it's purpose, you'd never not use it with `|raw`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why it didn't occur to me sooner, but I finally took a look at `twig_escape_filter`. It won't escape the string if it's an instance of `Twig_Markup`. Thus all we have to do is wrap our output in that:

```
class SpreadAttributes extends Twig_Node_Expression_Unary {
    public function compile(Twig_Compiler $compiler) {
        $compiler
            ->raw(__CLASS__ . '::attrs(')
            ->subcompile($this->getNode('node'))
            ->raw(', $this->env->getCharset())'); // not sure if this is the best way to pass the charset along, but it seems to work
    }

    public function operator(Twig_Compiler $compiler) {
        throw new \Exception("Unused");
    }

    public static function attrs($attrs, $charset) {
        return new Twig_Markup(WXU::html_attrs($attrs), $charset);
    }
}
```

Bam! No more escaping.

See [Ptilz](https://bitbucket.org/mnpenner/ptilz/src/86356a339f1b/src/Static/Html.php#Html.php-5) for an example implementation of `html_attrs`.

Comment: Hehe. Thanks for sharing!